# Select list value based on second column

Tags: linq

I have 2 column list value

```
ptext      |   stylename
-----------|------------
aaa        |   styleone
ccc        |   styleone
ddd        |   styleone
fff        |   styletwo
ggg        |   styletwo
xyx        |   styleone
dkk        |   styleone
```

I would like to have List like this

```
ptext           |  stylename
----------------|------------
aaa,ccc,ddd     |  styleone
fff,ggg         |  styletwo
xyx,dkk         |  styleone
```

please help using some linq query

Comment: It's OK for first question, but next time please provide code which you have tried

Comment: Why are `aaa,ccc,ddd` and `xyx,dkk` not in the same collection after projection?

Comment: I just want it should group by stylename and return comma delimited row   like I showed in desired list

Comment: because aaa,ccc,ddd is different row and xyx,dkk should be in different row this the requierement

Answer (score 1):

Group items by `stylename` property, then project each group `ptext` values into string joined with coma

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.stylename)
    .Select(g => new { 
        stylename = g.Key, 
        ptext = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.ptext)) 
    });
```

Or with query syntax:

```
from x in list
group x by x.stylename into g
select new { // or new YourItemType {
    stylename = g.Key, 
    ptext = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.ptext)) 
}
```

You can of course create objects of your list items type instead of anonymous objects.

Comment: It does not break first group then second group and third group

Comment: it just concatenate with comma delimited where I want I should be in 3 group for this example